# How long before usage are OAuth2.0 certificates published?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

Currently, I am writing server-side functionality to verify a JWT provided by the GCP Metadata Server (see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity for details).

In my first (dirty) implementation, I fetched Google's certificates from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs for every incoming request. This works like a charm, but does not really scale. So I want to cache the certificates.

One approach would be to create a cache that stores certificates corresponding with a `kid`. However, this allows an adversary to let the server make many requests to the Google server by sending false JWT's with random `kid`'s.

So what I rather want, is to store the complete response from the certificate endpoint. However, for this to work, I need know how long before usage the certificates are published.

I could not find anything about this any RFC, nor in the GCP documentation. Does anyone know if this is specified somewhere?

Comment: Your question is not clear `how long before usage...`. The certificates are rotated daily. I am not aware of the exact time. I would not worry about this endpoint scaling. For valid requests, you can cache the certificate based upon the `kid`. The problem is how to handle invalid requests. You specify JWT's provided by the Metadata server. This is a safe endpoint to call. How do you foresee someone forging these requests? To do so would mean a break in has occurred and then anything is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With "usage" I mean usage by GCP. So if Google rotates their keys, is the new certificate published before it is actually used for signing anything? If so, how long?

About trusting the metadata server: in my client, I get the tokens from the metadata server, but then send them to a public endpoint. I cannot trust that other users also get their tokens from the metadata server and do not create a bogus one themselves. Does that make sense?

Comment: 1/2) The following is my opinion. I don't have an authority (links) to refer you to. PKI is both complex and very simple. In order for Google to switch to a new signing certificate, Google must publish the public certificate before use, otherwise the entire signing process would collapse. When Google signs data (JWT), the default lifetime is 3600 seconds. I think that Google publishes two public keys so that Google can rotate from one to the other at a point in the day. This allows Google to replace one of the certificates each day or 12 hours.

Comment: 2/2) In my opinion, I would cache the two `kid` and for all others call the Google endpoint. Trying to implement your own logic might introduce bigger security problems.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! It does sound like the only safe approach without any reference to Google's practice. But it still annoys me a lot the public documentation does not support a "correct" implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question to the GCP support and they came back with the following:

> We cannot provide any guarantees about certificate rotation. The keys may rotate and additional valid certs may appear within the max-age. The server should pull [1] again to refresh the cert cache if it receives a token with an unknown kid.
>
> 1. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

So to summarize: it is only possible to cache individual keys, it is not possible to cache the complete result. Any cache misses should always be rechecked at Google's endpoint.